# cannot find symbol: class OneofDescriptor

Tags: java, scala, sbt, protocol-buffers

I have a sbt-protoc in my sbt project so upon `sbt compile`, .proto files will be compiled by protoc and will have a generated java class.

The plugin that I used came from this https://github.com/thesamet/sbt-protoc.

I specified the protobuf protoc setting to:

```
val protobufSetting = Compile / PB.targets := Seq(
  PB.gens.java("3.8.0") -> (Compile / sourceManaged).value
)
val protocVer = PB.protocVersion := "3.8.0"
```

then I added these settings to the module that I needed.

However, I am getting this error during compilation:

```
EventRecordsProtoOuterClass.java:1161:1: cannot find symbol
[error]   symbol:   class OneofDescriptor
[error]   location: class com.google.protobuf.Descriptors
[error]           com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.OneofDescriptor oneof) {
```

Please let me know how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: did you ever find a solution?